# Дождаться завершения php-процессов и перезагрузить Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

VDS Ubuntu 16.04
Периодически по Cron запускаются php-скрипты, которые работают продолжительное время (1-10 минут).

Необходимо сделать перезагрузку Ubuntu, дождавшись завершения запущенных php-процессов. При этом необходимо, чтобы пока ждем, новые php-процессы по Cron не запускались.

Как это можно сделать?

Конечно можно выключить cron-задачи, потом ждать завершения php-процессов, затем reboot, затем включить cron-задачи. Но может быть есть способ изящнее? ввел команду и пошел пить чай....

Comment: Почему бы не написать bash скрипт, со всеми этими непонятками, которые ты напихал в крон

Comment: можно в скрипте проверять наличие файла `/run/nologin`: он создаётся за 5 минут до указанного командой *shutdown* времени (`$ man shutdown`)

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам решение (можете тоже поставить на крон или написать bash скрипт)

```
pgrep -f "php script.php" || sudo reboot
```

с `sudo reboot` или без `sudo` в зависимости от вашего пользователя.

Работает так: если процесс с именем `php script.php` не найден в списке процессов, то перезагружаем систему.